# How to join table and display in single post with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have three tables

1. posts

   - id
   - cat_id
   - user_id
   - title
   - content
2. users

   - id
   - username
   - pass
3. categories

   - id
   - name

I have a code as follows:

**my posts controller**

```
$data['all_categories'] = $this->category_model->get_all_categories();
$data['posts'] = $this->post_model->get_posts();
$data['users'] = $this->user_model->get_user();

$this->load->view('pages/template', $data);
```

**my post_model**

```
$this->db->order_by('posts.id', 'DESC');
$this->db->join('categories', 'categories.id = posts.category_id');
$this->db->join('users', 'users.id = posts.user_id');
$query = $this->db->get('post');
return $query->result_array();
```

**my index view**

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
    <br>
    <div class="media">
        <div class="media-body" style="margin-left: 5px;">
            <h5><?php echo $post['title']; ?></h5>
            <small class="post-date"><span class="fa fa-user"></span> <strong><?php echo $post['username']; ?></strong> | <span class="fa fa-tags"></span> <strong><?php echo $post['name']; ?></strong></small><br>
            <?php echo character_limiter($post['content'], 250); ?>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I successfully displayed it in index view, but username and category name doesn't work in single post.

**My post view**

```
<h5><?php echo $post['title']; ?></h5>
<small class="post-date"><span class="fa fa-user"></span> <strong><?php echo $post['username']; ?></strong> | <span class="fa fa-tags"></span> <strong><?php echo $post['category_id']; ?></strong></small><br>
<?php echo $post['content']; ?>
```

Please help me guys. Thanks!

Comment: post.category_id should be posts.category_id in post_model

Comment: I have replaced it, but the result remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in your files.

**In Model**

```
public function load_posts(){
    $this->db->select('tbl_p.*, tbl_u.username, tbl_u.pass, tbl_c.name as category_name');        
    $this->db->from('posts as tbl_p');
    $this->db->join('users as tbl_u', 'tbl_u.id = tbl_p.user_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('categories as tbl_c', 'tbl_c.id = tbl_p.cat_id', 'left');
    $this->db->order_by('tbl_p.id', 'DESC');        
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return ($query->num_rows() > 0) ? $query->result_array() : false;        
}
```

**In Controller**

```
$data['posts'] = $this->post_model->load_posts();
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably is because of same row name. Use SELECT AS 'unique_name' for every row you are selecting.